# Checking if values in a dataframe exist and create a new dataframe with values 0/1 if the value exists or does not exist

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, string-comparison

I am very new to R and have been trying to do the following thing for hours:

I have a dataframe df:

```
id   charact.1   charact.2
1      0           0
2      0           1
3      1           1
4      0           1
```

Where the zeros and ones indicate if person with id = 1 and so on fulfills characteristic 1 or characteristic 2 or both.

Then, I have several text files for each person which contain the information about the characteristics. I read those files into several dataframes df1, df2, df3 and so on for every id looking like this:

```
(Example for id 3, df3)
Type of characteristic
  Charact. 1
  Charact. 2

(Example for id 4, df4)
Type of characteristic
  Charact. 2
```

What i want to do do now is the following:
Go through df1 and see if both character types occur in df1 and then set the values in df accordingly to 1 or 0 for each characteristic. Then do this for all dataframes df2, df3 and so on.
In my data the dataframes df1 and so on are named after the id names from df.

I feel like it should be something like combinations of for loops. But I have really no idea on how to further proceed here as my knowledge on R functions if very limited.

I hope this does make sense to anyone.
Thank you!

Comment: `df` has 3 columns: `id` and 2 characteristics, is that correct? And then you have a text file for each row of `df`?

Comment: How does the dataframe `df1` and `df2` look? Can you provide data using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @VitaminB16, yes exactly!